# iOS/iPhone -- How to implement a computer player (random actor) in matches with disconnected players?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, game-center, gamekit

First, I will confess that I haven't attempted this in code, so I apologize if this is jumping the gun.  I realize that adequate effort and research are a prerequisite to posting good questions.  But after reading GameKit and Game Center documentation, as well as iOS Developer Cookbooks, I can't seem to find the right functionality in GameKit and was wondering how I might venture outside it API-wise to solve this problem.

At the simplest level, I would like to implement a time-limited two-player game that does not shut down after one player disconnects, accidentally or maliciously (I currently make no distinction and do not know if I technically can).  Essentially, once a match is made, and the two-player match begins, I want the match to continue until one player wins, or match time (say, 10 minutes) expires.

The thing that I want advice on is how to keep a match going when one player disconnects.  (Currently, both players disconnecting simultaneously and prematurely leads to immediate termination of the match and no visible result, so no problem there.)  How do I set the iOS client to select an action randomly if the user is disconnected?  Do I need this program to run on the server, or on both iOS clients?  Is it best done in Objective-C to match the iOS applications, or should it be server-side code in some other networking language, like PHP?  Are there any APIs that handle this behavior well?  On each turn, much like rock-paper-scissors, players have a one-minute time limit to select an action like attack or defend, and if the timer expires without a selection, the computer program randomly selects an action for the player.  I'd like to treat a disconnected player the same way: If he or she isn't connected to the match to supply the choice of action, then the computer will do it randomly for him or her at the end of a minute, as if he or she were connected.  My purpose for keeping matches online like this is to (a.) ensure that players that disconnect shortly before losing will be assessed a proper loss, (b.) players that stay online in good faith will be assessed their deserved win, and (c.) players that disconnect accidentally or haphazardly can still salvage their match by returning in a timely fashion.  I'm sure lots of online games do this, but I just haven't found the proper API or past example for iOS, or two players connecting on their iPhones.  Game Center seems to drop the match, or in turn-based games, there isn't some enforceable turn timer (to my knowledge); I didn't see a way to tell who disconnected in the documentation, and I also didn't see some obvious way to keep something online in the case of failure, but with a timer continuing to run.  Everything in peer-to-peer seemed to simulate a client-server relationship (one peer the client, one the server), where if the server unit disconnects, the match must end, and if the disconnected player reconnects, the match cannot resume.

In short, I will not object to a code solution, but even some pointers or advice about a framework that supports this behavior will be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider [turn-based matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1) with timeouts? If a remote player does not respond (times out) control could return to the previous player, which could then conduct intermediate random moves as and while necessary. The application of timeouts for similar scenarios is e.g. discussed in a WWDC 2013 session video.

Comment: That's an interesting discussion.  I did consider it, but the one place where it differs is that, in my game, players submit their moves on the same clock; i.e. it is a turn-based game, but both players select their actions for their monsters, then the turn plays out with the fastest monster going first.  If there is a way to implement the simultaneous "turn" (both players select their moves before the turn happens for both of them to watch), then that's a solution.

Comment: @Cindeselia Well, if you want to model this as a turn-based game (it sounds like a bit of a stretch) I guess iOS 7 Game Center exchanges could help to sync players in addition to taking turns.

Comment: It is a turn-based game because each action is taken in a turn.  i.e. imagine Player A vs. Player B.  During turn 1, Player A and Player B select moves, and when both players have selected (or the time limit on the turn passes), the moves unfold without any dependence on real-time actions; the character with the highest speed goes first, and then the character with the next highest speed, and they take turns going until all commands selected have been executed. Then the turn 2 begins, and Player A and B again select moves. It isn't real-time - only in the sense that each turn has a time limit.

Comment: So there are definitely "turns" - each player selects moves in each turn, without knowing actually which move will execute first; part of the fun is having different speed stats on each character to determine order of execution. But there are definitely turns. Most people describe RPG battles as turn-based games. It's just a matter of not forcing oneself into Apple's model of having asynchronous move selection; if we did that, then players would have to wait too long for the battle to unfold. There is no need or dependence on one player finishing selection of a move before the other begins.

Answer (score 0):

If you've also implemented a mode where the user can start a game with a computer player locally, then it would be trivial to take any GameCenter game that's timed out and reload it as a local game against a UI.

My assumption would be that once you've implemented a local game with an AI whereby you're saving turns locally each time a player acts. Further, I'm assuming you would use the same data format for both types of games (perhaps changing a bit that says "computer player" instead of "remote player").

When the GC player times out, you code your game to swap out one type of player for another. Register in GC as a win/timeout, and allow the player to continue with the local/AI player.